# What's wrong with using depth render buffer? OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, depth-buffer

I use this code:

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context] || ![self loadShaders])
    {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

But when I'm runing the application I see purple screen? What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see where you bind your color renderbuffer to the to the CAEAGLLayer it is to be displayed on (although that may happen later), and I don't see you enabling depth testing.  Also, if I'm not mistaken you need to bind the color renderbuffer, call `glFramebufferRenderbuffer()` for that, then bind the depth renderbuffer and call it again.

The following is code that I've used to set up a similar display on OpenGL ES 2.0:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];

glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) 
{
    NSLog(@"Failure with framebuffer generation");
    return NO;
}
```

The full code of this application is available [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ShaderExamples.zip).

Answer (score 1):

I realize how old this is, but I did the exact same thing with the exact same results so I thought I would contribute. What had happened in my project was I hit the enter key too quickly on the auto-complete when setting up the render buffer, resulting in this:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
```

instead of this:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
```

End result: purple screen.